# Mode calculation is pulling from all data, not the subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Im creating a report in SSRS Report Builder 2016.

I have a set of data that contains a set of agencies and the amount of money that billed to each agency for each month (TotalBilled). Every agency can have multiple values for TotalBilled. I want to find the mode TotalBilled value for each agency.

I calculate the mode value inside my query, but it pulls from all TotalBilled in all agencies, and not just the TotalBilled related to the agency I have set in my parameter.

Here is my Dataset:

```
Select 
 a.AgencyID
 a.startdate,
 a.enddate,
 [TotalBilled],

 (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES TotalBilled
    From    invoiceLine I
    WHERE   TotalBilled <> 0
    GROUP BY TotalBilled
    ORDER BY Count(invl.TotalBilled) DESC ) AS ModeTotalBilled

from Agency a
left join invoiceLine invl
     on a.InvoiceID = invl.InvoiceID
where (a.agencyid in (@agency))
and (a.startdate >= @startdate and a.enddate <= @enddate)
```

I tried to join inside the mode query to the agency but it caused an error when running

```
 (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES TotalBilled
    From    invoiceLine I
    WHERE   TotalBilled <> 0
    AND     a.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID
    GROUP BY TotalBilled
    ORDER BY Count(invl.TotalBilled) DESC ) AS ModeTotalBilled
```

Error:

"Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)"

What is the right way to change my mode value calculation so that it is affected by my agency parameter and not just pulling from the whole database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT a.AgencyID, a.startdate, a.enddate,
       (SELECT TOP (1) i.TotalBilled
        FROM invoiceLine i
        WHERE i.TotalBilled <> 0 AND a.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
        GROUP BY i.TotalBilled
        ORDER BY COUNT(i.TotalBilled) DESC
       ) as ModeTotalBilled
FROM Agency a
WHERE a.agencyid = @agency AND
      a.startdate >= @startdate AND
      a.enddate <= @enddate;
```

I don't understand why you would be joining `invoice` in the outer query.  You should be qualifying all column names, especially when using correlated subqueries.

`TOP (1) WITH TIES` makes no sense in the subquery.  All that will do is return an error if more than one value qualifies as the mode.

Comment: My query actually pulls a lot more values from other tables as well. Above is what my query would look like with all other info removed. I make a couple of joins to get from agency to invoice in my original query.

Comment: My issue was that 'With Ties' was causing more than one value to be returned. Until i figure out how to handle multiple values for mode I will remove that. Thanks for the help!